# LM9022 add softstart for inrush current

Tags: inrush-current

I have a VFD filament driver ([LM92022](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM9022M/NOPB-National-Semiconductor-datasheet-11896945.pdf)) and i need to add a soft start for stop inrush current, for increase life time of the filament tube.

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533474/soft-start-circuit-design-for-audio-amplifier) solution its ok?

My tube working at 2.4v Ac / 80 ma.

[image]

LM9022 Scheamtic:
[image]

Comment: Does the LM9022 work at all at voltages lower than its designed 5 V?

Comment: Yes: Supply Voltage -0.3V to +6.0V from DS.

Comment: that's the *absolute maximum* values. It's not guaranteed to *work* under those conditions, it's just guaranteed that it won't be destroyed.

Comment: Minim 2V / Maxim 5.5V

Comment: In that case, you could soft start from 2 to 5 V, but it would still start up at 2 V. If that's good enough for you, go for it.

Comment: I need a diagram :)

Comment: Why not use an ICL instead? [Inrush Current Limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter)

Comment: Because power losses'